# Files I have hosted on a server get downloaded instead of opening in the browser when I click on links to them?

Tags: terminal, permissions, browser, webserver, web-hosting

I have a href link in a Latex document I'm creating that links to a Matlab file I have hosted on a server:

```
\href{https://www.college.edu/files/code.m}{Code}
```

However when you click this link in the PDF document generated by Latex the file gets downloaded instead of opening in the browser. I need it to open in the browser, like this Matlab file for example - http://users.ics.aalto.fi/ella/publications/cfastica_public.m

I thought this was a Latex issue so I posted it here [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334797/how-to-link-to-a-matlab-code-file-and-make-it-open-in-the-browser-instead-of-dow) but it seems Latex isn't the problem as if I create a link in Latex to the cfastica_public.m file mentioned above it opens in the browser. So what could be causing this issue where Matlab files I have hosted on a server get downloaded instead of opening in the browser? Could it be something to do with permissions? Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype

Comment: I don't have access to changing server parameters. Is that the only way to enable viewing in the browser of these files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way of forcing this behaviour without having access to the server where you upload your code. If you *really* need this behaviour, consider posting your code on a different server or post a copy on PasteBin instead.

Otherwise, you just have to deal with the download.